# Overlay bootstrap dropdown menu over hidden scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HenryVonfire/ez98t3z5/2/), how can I make the dropdown menu be shown over the previous divs? (I mean, not to be cut with the container and inner-container divs) I've played with position absolute/relative and z-index but I end up breaking the layout.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="box">
      div #1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      div #2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      div #3
      <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      div #4
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      div #5
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      div #6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.inner-container{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0 -30px 0 0;
  height: 200px;
}
.box{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:50px;
}
```

Comment: @close-voters: this question has a minimal reproducible exemple, is clear and definitely not too broad. It is on-topic and doesn't deserve being closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ez98t3z5/5/):

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
   position: fixed;
   left: auto;
   top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. The only problem is that when scrolling the menu is fixed to its position but that probably can't be solved.

Comment: You could treat your dropdown as a modal maybe if you like: https://jsfiddle.net/ez98t3z5/7/

Comment: yes, that's another option, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: I've have realized that it get stuck in its first position when it's shown. What means that, if I open it again after scrolling, it shows itself in the previous position, behaving weirdly.